# Creating a cross platform installer in Linux

Tags: java, linux, installation, cross-platform

How to create installer of say file which is swf and html and this html has to be created a short cut on the linux desktop . Is there any software that will solve my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [install4J](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) for the same.

Comment: Its sound good , i need to create a desktop shortcut file using install4J any thoughts on this ??

Comment: @Big Bang Theory : The installer goes through a wizard which has an option to create Desktop icon, tray icon etc. Through some customized coding you can also use your custom image for these icons. You can also localize it. Check http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/ for details.

Answer (score 2):

Edited: Use [izpack](http://izpack.org/downloads/).. It's a very simple java installer.

Comment: Looking for linux installer , NSIS is only for creating windows installer

Comment: Opps, sorry, my bungling attempt. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux distributions, installers are not the way to go. You should create *packages* that will be handled gracefully by the package manager.

This package will also allow you to define the dependencies your software have on other software, such as a Java runtime for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [list of open source installer generators](http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators) in Java.

I've used [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) myself for an installer that was required to run on Windows, Red Had Linux and Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

All the installers mentioned should do a good job addressing your requirements. If you do not want the overhead of a JRE, you can try [InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com), which produces natives installers (disclaimer, I am the author). Just create a shortcut in the Desktop using the GUI builder and automatically a .desktop file (the Linux equivalent of a Windows shortcut) will be created. InstallBuilder is a commercial tool but we have discount for solo developers and small shops, just drop as a line.